# Unable to find '' when compiling a NuGet package from an fsproj file

Tags: .net, f#, nuget

I get the following error when I try to compile a package from an `fsproj` file.

```
Unable to find ''. Make sure the project has been built.
```

(The project has been built)

Setting `-Verbosity detailed` gives me:

```
NuGet.CommandLineException: Unable to find ''. Make sure the project has been built.
   at NuGet.Commands.ProjectFactory.BuildProject()
   at NuGet.Commands.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder(String basePath)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommand.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommand.BuildPackage(String path)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.Commands.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

My commandline is this:

```
..\.nuget\nuget pack Imms.FSharp.fsproj
```

The same thing happens when I do:

```
..\.nuget\nuget pack Imms.FSharp.fsproj -Prop Configuration=Release -Prop Platform=AnyCPU
```

It doesn't matter what `nuspec` or configuration I use.

Comment: Have you *compiled* the project first?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yes, of course :)

Comment: IIRC NuGet doesn't understand. fsproj files, which is why I, in ZeroToNine, use .nuspec files: https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine/blob/master/NuGetSpecs/Ploeh.ZeroToNine.nuspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it doesn't matter anymore, but for those with the same problem. After downloading latest nuget (v3.5.0) from nuget.org and using it everything worked. Previously i've been using nuget 1.7 and got the same error as op.